# Unresolved external error in building ZeroMQ library for x64 architecture but works perfectly fine for 32 bit

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, zeromq, failed-installation

I installed ZeroMQ for c++ using this [link](https://github.com/zeromq/czmq#using-cmake). I followed the CMake approach to build the `libsodium` and `libzmq` project. After successfully completing all the steps, I am able to build and run my application on VS2015 for both release and debug mode for 32 configuration. But when I try to build the same project with x64 configuration I get the following errors:

```
1>zmqClientCPP.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_zmq_send
1>zmqClientCPP.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_zmq_ctx_destroy
1>zmqClientCPP.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_zmq_setsockopt
1>zmqClientCPP.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_zmq_socket
1>zmqClientCPP.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_zmq_strerror
1>zmqClientCPP.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_zmq_close
1>zmqClientCPP.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_zmq_connect
1>zmqClientCPP.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_zmq_ctx_set
1>zmqClientCPP.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_zmq_errno
1>zmqClientCPP.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_zmq_ctx_new
1>zmqClientCPP.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_zmq_msg_init
1>zmqClientCPP.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_zmq_msg_data
1>zmqClientCPP.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_zmq_msg_size
1>zmqClientCPP.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_zmq_msg_recv
1>zmqClientCPP.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_zmq_msg_close
1>zmqClientCPP.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_zmq_getsockopt
```

I have tried the following:

- added `#define ZMQ_STATIC` before `#include <zmq.hpp>`.
- did the linking in the project configuration:

  `properties - > configuration properties -> c/c++ -> General ->  additional include directories : C:\libzmq\include;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)`

  `properties - > configuration properties -> Linker -> Input : libzmq-v140-mt-4_3_3.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)`

  `properties - > configuration properties -> Linker -> General -> Additional Library directories : C:\libzmq\lib\;%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)`

Still the problem is not resolved.

I am not sure what I am missing. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Note that the configuration is separate for 32bit and 64bit builds, and again separate for debug and release builds. Also note that you cannot link the 32bit library in the 64bit build.

Comment: @Botje thanks for your response. Any suggestions where can I find the `libzmq` for 64 bit?

Comment: Wherever you got the 32bit version from and/or by compiling it yourself, I would guess.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, everyone for your help.

Finally, the issue got resolved by following the below steps:

1. Install `vcpkg` using the following steps:

   `C:\>git clone https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg.git`

   `C:\>cd vcpkg`

   `C:\vcpkg>bootstrap-vcpkg.bat`

After it is successfully installed, you can check for all the available packages by using

`C:\vcpkg> vcpkg search` command or you can filter out by typing the filter name like `C:\vcpkg>vcpkg.exe search zmq` you would see the results something like shown below:

[image: Search results for "zmq"]

2. Once we are done with installing `vcpkg`, we have to install `zeromq` using the following command:

   `C:\vcpkg> vcpkg.exe install zeromq:x64-windows-static` (In my case I'm installing for 64 bit)
3. After this, we are all set for building our own project with `zeromq`. We can refer [this](http://jotmynotes.blogspot.com/2019/04/build-and-static-link-zeromq-on-windows.html) for in case we need some help with linking the libraries.